# How do I correctly spread 2 arrays overwriting the old values that matches the object id

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, spread

My goal is to combine the values in both arrays, overwriting the objects that matches all the _id. Is this possible?

```
oldState = [
               { _id: 1, label: 'a' },
               { _id: 2, label: 'b' }, 
               { _id: 3, label: 'c' }
           ]

newState = [
               { _id: 2, label: 'updated b' },
               { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }
           ]

Expected Result:
           [
               { _id: 1, label: 'a' },
               { _id: 2, label: 'updated b' }, 
               { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }
           ]
```

Doing this:

```
[...oldState, ...newState]
```

Results to this:

```
[
    { _id: 1, label: 'a' },
    { _id: 2, label: 'b' }, 
    { _id: 3, label: 'c' },
    { _id: 2, label: 'updated b' }, 
    { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }
]
```

Comment: Spreading is not meant to do so (not in the way you are using it, at least). Other than that, you have different object references, so the best solution would be to build the new array by aggregating the two arrays considering `_id` as the key.

Comment: Since the`_id` is only an attribute of the item and not the element it self, you cannot do it by a simple spread but rather would need a reduce or some other iteration

Comment: Does the final order of the elements matter?

Answer (score 2):

You must note that spread syntax cannot in itself overrider objects with specific key, you need to do that yourself.

You can make use of `Array.prototype.reduce` and group the object based on _id and overwrite objects with the same id.

```js
var oldState = [
               { _id: 1, label: 'a' },
               { _id: 2, label: 'b' }, 
               { _id: 3, label: 'c' }
           ]

var newState = [
               { _id: 2, label: 'updated b' },
               { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }
           ]
           
const res = oldState.concat(newState).reduce((acc, item) => {
   acc[item._id] = {...(acc[item._id] || {}), ...item};
   return acc;
}, {})

const sol = Object.values(res);
console.log(sol);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use `Array.reduce()` with a Map as the accumulator. The code is a bit cleaner, and the Map also preserves the original order of the items (an object would order them by the numeric value of `_id`):

```js
const oldState = [{"_id":1,"label":"a"},{"_id":2,"label":"b"},{"_id":3,"label":"c"}]
const newState = [{"_id":2,"label":"updated b"},{"_id":3,"label":"updated c"}]
           
const result = Array.from(
  [...oldState, ...newState]
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc.set(item._id, item), new Map())
    .values()
)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I didn't think about relying on maps, although that's indeed a clever way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) from your `newState` with the keys being the object ids and the values being the objects themselves. Then you can map your `oldState` and replace any old objects with the new objects in from the Map if its id exists:

```js
const oldState = [{ _id: 1, label: 'a' }, { _id: 2, label: 'b' }, { _id: 3, label: 'c' } ];
const newState = [{ _id: 2, label: 'updated b' }, { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' } ];

const newStateMap = new Map(newState.map(o => [o._id, o]));
const res = oldState.map(o => newStateMap.get(o._id) || o);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd reduce all items to an object and then get the object's values:

```js
const oldState = [
  { _id: 1, label: 'a' },
  { _id: 2, label: 'b' }, 
  { _id: 3, label: 'c' }
];

const newState = [
  { _id: 2, label: 'updated b' },
  { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }
];

const merge = (oldState, newState) => Object.values(
  [...oldState, ...newState].reduce((a, v) => (a[v._id] = v, a), {})
);

console.log(merge(oldState, newState));
```

Comment: Clever usage of `Object.values` here.

Answer (score 0):

You could build objects and spred it into a new object and ge the values from it.

```js
const
    getObject = (array, key) => Object.fromEntries(array.map(o => [o[key], o])),
    oldState = [{ _id: 1, label: 'a' }, { _id: 2, label: 'b' }, { _id: 3, label: 'c' }],
    newState = [{ _id: 2, label: 'updated b' }, { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }],
    result = Object.values({
        ...getObject(oldState, '_id'),
        ...getObject(newState, '_id')
    });

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create an object which will contain unique items and then use `map` method to create merged object:

```js
const oldState = [
  { _id: 1, label: 'a' },
  { _id: 2, label: 'b' },
  { _id: 3, label: 'c' }
];

const newState = [
  { _id: 2, label: 'updated b' },
  { _id: 3, label: 'updated c' }
];

const mapping = new Map(newState.map(s => [s._id, s]))
const result = oldState.map((s, i)=> ({ ...mapping.get(s._id) || s}));
console.log(result);
```